# Changing a css background image with WordPress REST API (JSON)

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, rest, api

I managed to display the value on my console.log but when I use the value that I extracted from WordPress REST API to change a CSS Background image, I got an "undefined" value. I'm trying to create a static HTML but display a blog featured image on my site.

JS:

```
var newImage;
var postRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
postRequest.open('GET','http://method.com.sg/post/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
postRequest.onload = function(){
var ourData = JSON.parse(postRequest.responseText);
newImage = ourData[0].better_featured_image.source_url;

console.log(newImage); //Will output the hyperlink
};
alert(newImage); // Output Undefined
postRequest.send();

//Unable to work
$('.container.withBg.post').css('background-image', 'url('+newImage+')');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because the alert() will not have required url which will only be available once the request is loaded but the alert will not wait for that task to complete and will execute prematurely. 
You can try create a dummy function to handle the change of bg image, which will be called once the url is available as below:

```
var newImage;
var postRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
postRequest.open('GET','http://method.com.sg/post/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
postRequest.onload = function(){
var ourData = JSON.parse(postRequest.responseText);
newImage = ourData[0].better_featured_image.source_url;

console.log(newImage); //Will output the hyperlink

//Make a function call here to change the background url
change_background(newImage);
};
postRequest.send();

function change_background(newImage){
    alert(newImage); // Output Undefined
    $('.container.withBg.post').css('background-image', 'url('+newImage+')');
}
```

You can change the function name to whatever you want.

Comment: Ah that works! The dummy function saved my life. Thank you @yamu Yamu.